# Proving that $\angle AOE = 2 \angle COD$ using complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Suppose $OABC$ is a square, with points $D$ and $E$ on line segment $BC$ such that $BD = CD$ and $BE = DE.$ Prove that $\angle AOE = 2 \angle COD$ using complex numbers.

I noted that $\triangle COD$ was a right triangle with $CD:CO = 1:2,$ so I knew $\sin(\angle COD) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.$ However, I got stuck from here on out.

Comment: Hint: work with tan instead, and let, e.g., $O=0$, $A=4$ and $C=4i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of $D$, the midpoint of $BC$, work with $F$, the midpoint of $AB$. Since $\angle COD=\angle AOF$.

Set $O=0,A=1,B=1+i,C=i,E=\frac{3}{4}+i$

Then $F=1+\frac{1}{2}i$

$$z_F^2=\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}i \right)^2=\frac{3}{4}+i=z_E$$

$$\Rightarrow \arg(z_E)=2\arg(z_F)$$

$$\therefore \angle AOE=2\angle AOF=2\angle COD$$